# change the default path where Latex looks for everything

Tags: input, external-files

I'm trying to throw different projects into one document that are in different folders. These folders include images and texfiles. I know that I can always include files with `\input{}` or `\include{}` like this:

```
\input{<path1>/texfile1}
\input{<path2>/texfile2}
```

but this runs into problems as soon as `texfile1` for example includes a graph that is stored in a subfolder of `<path1>`. In effect, I want to do something like changing the working directory of a statistical program like this:

```
% change directory to <path1>
```

input several files that again include images etc just as if I were compiling a latex document inside `<path1>`

```
% now change directory to <path2>
```

and input all the files from there as if I were in that folder

I've tried playing with `TEXINPUTS=` as suggested [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-graphicspath) but couldn't get it to work. A workaround I have in mind is including the path inside every `\input{}` and changing `\graphicspath{}` in between the two projects but it seems that there must be a less hack-y solution, no?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/import

Comment: To get accurate result you need to give clear example of what you use (mwe) based on current description the texinputs= for ubuntu would need to be .:path1/:path2/: but more importantly for your description \graphicspath in each document needs to be something like {{.//}{path1/}{path2/}{./}}

Comment: the import package is what I was looking for, thanks! works like a charm